# How to remove a member from a MS teams chat

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft-teams

I was once asked to join a MS teams meeting which was part of a series of meetings. Ever since I can read their chat and messages of people starting or leaving the meeting, although I should not be part of the series.

I know how to leave that chat myself, but what about the original members – can they remove me so I cannot read their privat chat? If I want someone to join our meeting just once: How can I keep them from staying part of the chat forever?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,Others could remove you from a group chat as follows:

[image]

Note: Your admin will need to turn on this setting to allow members to remove each other from a group chat.

People removed from a chat will be able to view previous chat history, but won't be able to send new messages, react to messages, and won't be able to view new conversations or files shared by the group.

More information for your reference:

[https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/leave-or-remove-someone-from-a-group-chat-7db55a67-0ba4-4409-a399-5ed502a1d094#:~:text=Open%20any%20group%20chat%20of,remove%20the%20participant%20from%20chat](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/leave-or-remove-someone-from-a-group-chat-7db55a67-0ba4-4409-a399-5ed502a1d094#:%7E:text=Open%20any%20group%20chat%20of,remove%20the%20participant%20from%20chat).